# Hide PayPal button with fundingSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

My code was working fine.

I am trying to hide the PayPal button, when I did, it goes to wrong url: `https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?`

As you can see we need here latinumcheckout not checkoutnow? What to do ? Thanks.

```js
var FUNDING_SOURCES = [paypal.FUNDING.BANCONTACT, paypal.FUNDING.IDEAL];

FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function (fundingSource) {
  var button = paypal
    .Buttons({
      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          shipping_type: "PICKUP",
          application_context: { shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING" },
          purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                value: "88.44",
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      },
      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
          console.log(
            "Capture result",
            orderData,
            JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2)
          );
          var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
          alert(
            "Transaction " +
              transaction.status +
              ": " +
              transaction.id +
              "\n\nSee console for all available details"
          );
        });
      },
      fundingSource: fundingSource,
    })
    .render("#bancontact-button-container");
});
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Testing Payments</title>
    <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&components=buttons,payment-fields,marks,funding-eligibility&enable-funding=bancontact&currency=EUR"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        paypal.Marks({
            fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.BANCONTACT
        }).render('#bancontact-mark')

        paypal.PaymentFields({
            fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.BANCONTACT,
            style: {
                // style object (optional)
            },
            fields: {
                // fields prefil info (optional)
                name: {
                    value: "John Doe",
                },
            }
        }).render("#bancontact-container");

        paypal.Buttons({
            fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.BANCONTACT,
            style: {
                label: "pay",
            },
            createOrder() {
                return fetch("/my-server/create-paypal-order", {
                    method: "post",
                    // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
                    // like product skus and quantities
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        cart: [
                            {
                                sku: "YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT",
                                quantity: "YOUR_PRODUCT_QUANTITY",
                            },
                        ],
                    }),
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((order) => order.id);
            },
            onApprove(data) {
                return fetch(`"/my-server/capture-paypal-order`, {
                    method: "post",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        orderID: data.orderID
                    })
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((orderData) => {
                        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                        const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                        console.log('Transaction Status:', transaction.status);
                        console.log('Transaction ID:', transaction.id);
                        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                        // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                        // Or go to another URL:  window.location.href = 'thank_you.html';
                    });
            },
            onCancel(data, actions) {
                console.log(`Order Canceled - ID: ${data.orderID}`);
            },
            onError(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })
            .render("#bancontact-btn");

    </script>

    <div id="bancontact-mark">
    </div>
    <div id="bancontact-container">
    </div>
    <div id="bancontact-btn">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to hide the PayPal button using `fundingSource`, but when I click on the button like baancontact or ideal I went to url start with checkoutnow? normally should be start with latinumcheckout, any advice to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks correct, yet I can reproduce the problem and it would appear to be a bug. Contact PayPal for support on why the wrong URL is opening.

By the way, actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated, no longer supported for new integrations. Use the /v2/checkout/orders API to create and capture the order on a server backend. See the documentation/samples at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @Preston PHX Yes I am using "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/" on the backend. I did Contact PayPal for support , And I am waiting for a solution.

Comment: PayPal did not help me, Can anyone suggest a way to hide the PayPal button or disable it? @Preston PHX

Comment: Test again, it seems to have been fixed

Comment: It only works in test mode, what do you think?

Comment: Report the bug to PayPal again.